# remove breakline (\n) inbetween two "

Tags: php, regex

Im asking here again :)

Let's say I have a string in PHP, something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit. "Sed et est eget lorem congue
eleifend. Fusce luctus"
```

Right, so you see the string in those two quote sings ---> ", right, if there's a text, in db, between those two quote signs, it shouldnt have break line like this, is there a way, in regex with preg_replace function in PHP to target break lines inbetween those two symbols and delete them?

Thanks for your time guys,
Mart

Comment: No, I want to remove the breakline, only the breakline is inbetween two quote sings " ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems concerning matched or nested elements (in this case matched quotation marks) are usually a bit awkward with regular expressions.

First, let me make an assumption here: escaped quotation marks inside quotation marks are not allowed in your input (i.e. you never have `Lorem "ipsem \" dolor"` or something like this).

With this assumption, your problem boils down to this: find a `\n` that is followed by an odd number of `"` (counting until the end of the string). To ensure this condition, we can use a lookahead. To avoid problems with leading or trailing whitespace, we can match any whitespace surround an `\n` and replace it with a single space.

```
$result = preg_replace('/\s*\n\s*(?=[^"]*"(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/', ' ', $input);
```

You might want to replace that `\n` with `[\r\n]` for interoperability.

Comment: That is perfection itself my friend ... thank you very much for the explanation and the time you spent on this! Amazing. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the built in escaping function, e.g. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php.  This way they'll be escaped, meaning you'll keep the information, but it'll be database friendly.